# ExtJS Combobox with Text and Button

Tags: extjs

I have a Combobox (ExtJs 6) and i want to show a value and delete-button in each row of the list.
I've tried with XTemplate, but then no value is selected any more and I don't know how to call a function from the delete button.
How can i do this? Any examples appreciated.

Comment: You should show what you have tried so the answer can help you understand where you went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main parts are:

- Create a template that renders your button in the dropdown
- Listen for itemclick events on the dropdown and stop the event, removing the item from the store if the user clicked on a button

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1j7r

```
    var combo = Ext.create({
        xtype: 'combo',
        editable: false,
        store: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],

        listConfig: {
            listeners: {
                itemclick: function(list, record, item, index, e) {
                    if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        combo.store.removeAt(index);
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        tpl: '<ul class="x-list-plain"><tpl for="."><li role="option" class="x-boundlist-item">{field1}<button>x</button></li></tpl></ul>',

    });
```

While [@Mr.George's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40240988/227299) does the trick, it suffers from a few problems:

- Updating the value of the store just to display a button in the drop down; should use a template instead. That also causes the HTML to be displayed in the combo's text field
- JavaScript inside the HTML. Use event handlers instead
- Relying on `Ext.getCmp` which means it relies on a global id, so you can't have two instances on the same page

Comment: nice ty @Juan Mendes

Comment: For extjs 4, need to attach handler to `beforeitemclick` event and return `false` to prevent item selecting

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1j77

you can do that

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    Ext.create({
        xtype:'window',
        width:200,
        height:200,
        items:[{
            xtype:'combo',
            id:'myCombo',
            editable:false,
            store:['val1','val2','val3'],
            listeners:{
                afterrender:function(combo){
                    var records=combo.store.data.items;
                    records.forEach(function(rec,index){
                        var field= rec.get('field1');
                        rec.set('field1',
                                ''+field+' <button onclick="'+
                                'Ext.getCmp(\'myCombo\').store.remove(Ext.getCmp(\'myCombo\').store.findRecord(\'field1\',\''+
                                field+'\'));">Delete</button>');

                    });
                }
            }
        }]
    }).show();
}
```

});

Comment: It does work, I almost upvoted, but my conscience won't let me do it if you're adding inline JavaScript in 2016. Also, using `Ext.getCmp('myCombo')` means it won't be reusable (can only have one per page). I'd vote it up if you explained that this is hacked together and explained its pitfalls

Comment: So, you can try to add a button in an extjs combobox in an other way if you want, in my opinion this is one of the easiest way. Others ways are to append the button component to a specific id in the dom, so the problem is almost the same. or add with a TPL the component, so you can't get the viewcontroller from the tpl.

Comment: Another problem is that you shouldn't be editing the value of the combo, `combo.getValue()` will now return a string with the HTML button